# How to swipe up a fragment from a button with a circular animation in Android?

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, fragment, swipe

i have seen the lockscreen on the galaxy s6 where there are a phone button and a camera button, when user starts swiping them upwards, the fragment begins to reveal in a circular animation. 
I need to achieve the exact thing in my app, but i don't know where to start. I've searched a lot of github projects and examples but still it seems that nobody has recreated that yet. does anyone has any idea ?

[Here's an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsXTN.png)

[Here's an other example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrjHq.png)